# Change Value in Excel According to a Reference Table based Upon a Selection

Tags: excel, vlookup

and sorry for my bad english.
Scenario: In the first worksheet I have a worksheet with two columns - Category and ID:

```
A1 - Product    B1 - ID
A2 - Apple      B2 - 10
A3 - Banana     B3 - 20
A4 - Coconut    IB4 - 30
```

Then I have second worksheet with cell column "A1 Product" linked to sheet1!A with a dropdown menu and I select apple, banana, or coconut. Then I want sheet2 B1 to show ID, depending upon the selection in sheet2 A1.

If I select banana in A1 I want in B1 to show the ID of banana - 20, if I select coconut in A1 I would like it to show 30 in B1

Comment: Accept your answers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Use the VLOOKUP function.

The syntax is:
=VLOOKUP(lookup_value,look_up_table_range,column_index,FALSE)

Lookup value should refer to apple or banana in the sheet/table you want to update, the look up table range refers to the table of the fruits and their id (use $ in the reference as below to ensure this does not move when you click and drag). In this the function will look up the value in the left-most column of this table and return the value in the column defined by the column index (in this case col_index=2). The FALSE provides an exact rather than an approximate match which is what you would want with IDs.

For example in this case put this in B1 of sheet 2 (click and drag as required for the values below, note that the $ signs before the references indicate that these do not move with click and drag):

```
=vlookup(sheet2!A1,sheet1!$A$2:$B$4,2,FALSE)
```

The Microsoft information page is [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-au/excel-help/vlookup-HP005209335.aspx).

Comment: The formmula syntax is all wrong. Also note that when you omit the fourth parameter from VLookup it defaults to 1 or TRUE, which means that lookup table must be sorted ascending by the first column. Otherwise there will be wrong results.

Comment: Thanks for the pickup. It was a careless mistake I shouldn't have made. I don't think down-voting and posting a less complete answer is in the spirit of the community though.